# Node Js write File from base64 result error "Invalid JPEG structure : two SOF Marker" when decode from php base64 string

Tags: php, android, node.js, base64

I have a Node Js which can retrieve base64 string and save it into image, this is my Node Js Code :

=== NODE JS CODE ===

```
var q = req.body;
var extention = ".jpg";
var dir = "img/customer/idcard/";

var base64Data = q.image.replace(/^data:image\/\w+;base64,/, "");

fs.unlink("../" + dir + OldGambar + extention, (err) => {
  if (err) console.log(err);
 // console.log(OldGambar + ' was deleted');
});

require("fs").writeFile("../" + dir + NewGambar + extention, base64Data, 'base64', function(err) {
  if (err) console.log(err);
});
```

Below is my code for converting Image into Base64 string using Android (JAVA) :

```
Bitmap image = ((BitmapDrawable) varimgIDCard.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
Encode = Base64.encodeToString(byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray(),Base64.DEFAULT);
```

while in JAVA, all working correctly and the image itself can be opened without any error

And below is my code for converting Image into Base64 using PHP :

```
$path = $dest.$a;
$type = pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$data = file_get_contents($path);
$strimg = 'data:image/' . $type . ';base64,' . base64_encode($data);
```

The above code also has no problem or error when creating a file, But when I opened the file. it resulting error "Invalid JPEG structure : two SOF Marker"

why is that happening? am I doing something wrong in PHP encoding?

by the way, here the result of SUCCESS Base64 from Android (JAVA) :
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1G2XHJxE6QJ0GjQcU5pclP3x7mIxMECzo

by the way, here the result of UNSUCCESSFUL Base64 from PHP :
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1PXueFtaws5iT-BlFbpvoGhNzCmT6_8Lp

And yes, for some reason, base64 from PHP is one-liner while Android is not which probably is the most reason why the PHP failed.

oh, and here the screenshot of the image which can't be opened from base64 PHP :

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was actually very simple, I take a look and check for a difference between both Base64 Before Sent and Base64 After Sent, and in the latter Base64 was missing character '+'.

POST PHP was removing '+' line from my Base64, so I using str_replace and change the code from this :

```
$path = $dest.$a;
$type = pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$data = file_get_contents($path);
$strimg = 'data:image/' . $type . ';base64,' . base64_encode($data);
```

Into This :

```
$path = $dest.$a;
$type = pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$data = file_get_contents($path);
$strimg = 'data:image/' . $type . ';base64,' . base64_encode($data);
$strimg = str_replace("+","%2B",$strimg);
```

And now all working correctly